# "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true not working still getting System.Drawing.Common is not supported on non-Windows platforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error:

System.Drawing.Common is not supported on non-Windows platforms When trying to use System.Drawing.Common, I found this solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only

And now I am trying to set EnableUnixSupport to true by doing the following:

1. Created a file in my project called runtimeconfig.template.json and adding the following:

   {
   "configProperties": {
   "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
   }
   }
2. run dotnet build
3. I can see a new version of the file [appname].runtimeconfig.json has been created and looks like this:

   {
   "runtimeOptions": {
   "tfm": "net6.0",
   "frameworks": [
   {
   "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
   "version": "6.0.0"
   },
   {
   "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
   "version": "6.0.0"
   }
   ],
   "configProperties": {
   "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true,
   "System.GC.Server": true,
   "System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.IsSupported": true,
   "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
   }
   }
   }

I run my project and I see get the exception when using System.Drawing.Common

Shouldn't this fix my problem?

Comment: What exact error do you get and what method are you trying to call? As the linked article says - _"`libgdiplus` is the main provider of the cross-platform implementation of `System.Drawing.Common` on the native side. .... It's around 30,000 lines of C code that's largely untested, and it **lacks a lot of functionality.**"_ and _"`System.Drawing.Common` will continue to evolve only in the context of Windows Forms and GDI+."_

Comment: That compatibility switch is .NET 6 only, so if you are on 7/8 it won’t work any more.